# Animated canvas background flashing?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to make a typing game with moving words on a canvas, which move left to right and lives are lost if they leave the canvas however i'm trying to animate a simple looping background image for my canvas, I have gotten it working and looping and moving left, however for some reason when this is in use my entire canvas is flashing as if it is constantly redrawing in a strange way or something I don't really know.

```
var canvas;
 var canvasContext;
let x=20;
var string;
let score = 0;
let highscore = 0;
var lives = 3;
var WordID;
var difficultyWordID
var bg = new Image();
bg.src = "client/img/stars.jpg";



window.onload = function(){

canvas = document.getElementById('typingCanvas');
var typeval = document.getElementById("typingValue");       //user typed value.
canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.getElementById("Button2").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("gameOver").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("scoreText").style.display = "none";
let fps=40;
setInterval(function(){
    if(x==20){
        string = getWord()
    }
    moveEverything()
    drawEverything(x,string);

    if (x>900) {
        lives--;
    } else if (lives<1) {
          canvas.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("Button2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("GameTable").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("gameHR2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("gameHR3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("gameOver").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("scoreText").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("GameHeading").textContent = "Results below: ";
        document.getElementById("scoreText").textContent = "Your Score: " + score;


        function updateUserScore() {

            fetch("/leaderboard/update", {method: 'post', body: formData}
            ).then(response => response.json()
            ).then(responseData => {

                if (responseData.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                    alert(responseData.error);
                } else {


                }
            });
        }

    }


    if(x>900 || check()){
        x=20;
        document.getElementById("val").value = '';      //if inputed value get match then blank the input box.


    }
},1000/fps)
}

function drawEverything(x,string ){ // draws text etc
canvasContext.fillStyle="rgba(0,0,200,0)";      //  background colour
canvasContext.border="white"
canvasContext.fillRect(20,20,canvas.width,canvas.height);
drawString(x,string);
scoreBoard(score);
highScoreBoard(highscore);


}

function moveEverything(){
x+=4; // movement speed of the word
}


function drawString(x,string) {
canvasContext.font="30px Verdana";
canvasContext.fillStyle='gray';
canvasContext.fillText(string,x,280);  // place of text appearing.
}

function Background(){ // sets background
this.x = 0, this.y = 0, this.w = bg.width, this.h = bg.height;
this.render = function(){
    canvasContext.drawImage(bg, this.x--, 0);
    if(this.x <= -499){
        this.x = 0;
    }
}
}
var background = new Background(); // actual background animation
function animate(){
  background.render();

}
 var animateInterval = setInterval(animate, 40);


 function getWord(WordID) {
WordID = Math.floor(Math.random()*30) +1
difficultyWordID = WordID

if (WordID === null) {

} else
    fetch("/words/single/" + WordID, {method: 'get'}
     ).then(response => response.json()
    ).then(responseData => {
        if (responseData.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
        alert(responseData.error);
    } else {
       string = responseData.Definition;


    }
});
}


function check(WordID){
var userVal = document.getElementById("val").value;
if(userVal==string){
    return true;
}
return false;
}

function scoreVal(){
if(check()){
    fetch("/words/single/"  + difficultyWordID, {method: 'get'}
    ).then(response => response.json()
    ).then(responseData => {
        if (responseData.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
            alert(responseData.error);
        } else {
            let difficultyScore  = 1;
            difficultyScore = responseData.Difficulty;
            score=score + difficultyScore;

        }
    });
}
}

function highScoreVal(){
if(score>highscore){
    highscore=score;
}
}

  function scoreBoard(score){
scoreVal(WordID);
canvasContext.fillStyle = "White";
canvasContext.font = "40px hot_sauceitalic";
canvasContext.fillText("Your Score: ",50,60);
canvasContext.fillStyle = "White";
canvasContext.fillText(score, 250, 60);
}
function highScoreBoard(highscore){
highScoreVal();
canvasContext.fillStyle = "White";
canvasContext.fillText("Lives:",750,60);
canvasContext.fillStyle = "White";
canvasContext.font = "40px hot_sauceitalic";
canvasContext.fillText(lives, 850, 60);
}
```

I am unsure how to go about fixing this as I cant really work out the problem myself, I am assuming that it is to do with how it is drawing the background alongside the moving words.

EDIT - Tried using background-image and got this instead.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhNai.png

Comment: _“as if it is constantly redrawing”_ - well it _is_ … If you have a “background” covering the whole canvas, and you now move that background in any direction, doesn’t matter if by just one pixel or more, _of course_ the whole thing has to be re-drawn. If you don’t need to do any pixel manipulation of the background image itself - then you’re likely much better off applying it as an _actual_ `background-image` for your canvas element, so that it can shine through in all the places where your canvas content is transparent.

Comment: I have already tried that, however when I use background-image my word that is being drawn leaves behind a trail making it unreadable. - Check the edit

Comment: @Rhys - the idea with a background-image is that you only have to explicitly draw part of the canvas. The browser will take care of putting it in the background. However - you're still expected to clear the canvas before drawing something new to it. ;)